# Rendering RDLC to pdf output console application

Tags: c#, reporting-services, console-application, rdlc, rdl

I have referred some articles in this website for Rendering .rdlc to .pdf output using console application.Am new to C# .net built a application for the same as below gives an error saying
:>Rdclrender.exe!Rdclrender.Program.Main(string[] args = {string[0]}) Line 28 
My class is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;


namespace Rdclrender
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Variables
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;


            // Setup the report viewer object and get the array of bytes
            ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
            viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";


            byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("output.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            // Now that you have all the bytes representing the PDF report, buffer it and send it to the client.
            /*  Response.Buffer = true;
              Response.Clear();
              Response.ContentType = mimeType;
              Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "." + extension);
              Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
              Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download*/
        }
    }
}
```

Is this is the way to create pdf from .rdl? I had renamed my .rdl to .rdlc manually an added .rdlc item to project.

Comment: Yes, I did it the same way in my WinForms Project, we use clientside reports as well.

Comment: @Dannydust Can you manke-out what is the error i mentioned? I want to save the report locally to disc.Not to show up using report viewer. It should be a background process.

Comment: Can't you debug your application? It's really hard to say what is going wrong. It would be nice if you could post an exception. But 2 questions: Do you have an existing report file with the name: "Report.rdlc"? And if yes can you put the full path there f. e. viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"c:\myfolder\Report.rdlc";

Comment: Yes full path has been given.I tried debugging and the exception was "Local processing Exception was unhandled"

Comment: Ok then check out the Inner Exceptions, it's really hard to find the errors when deialing with this technology. Check all the Exception Information carefully. Maybe there is a bit more of information.
And please check the LocalReport Property of your viewer Control.

Comment: the inner exception is - "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source \"Sales\"." . I am using the Adventureworks DB in this.How to add data source since am not using winForm controls UI?

Comment: It would be the easiest way to define the Datasource as an embedded Datasource in the report itself.
Refer to this article:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159165.aspx

Comment: But i cant add data source as they explained(there is no report data pane since its a console app).I have renamed a .rdl file to rdlc where .rdl had a embedded data source.Do i have to define a new data source programatically? if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay to do it programatically the simplest solution is:

Fill a DataTable with the Data for the Report and name the Datatable "Sales" (like the DataSource name in your report.

Please note this is pseudo code which will not work but should give you an idea.

```
var myDataSet = new DataSet(); 
var da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Sales", "yourConnectionstring");

da.Fill(myDataSet);
DataTable table = myDataSet.Tables[0];
table.TableName = "Sales";
```

Add the DataTable as a Datasource to your report:

```
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(table);
```

Comment: Got it but an unfamiliar error pops up : error rsInvalidReportDefinition: The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Comment: So now you gat a different error. This error means that your rendering engine does not fit the version of your report. Make sure your Reporting Dlls match the Version of your report.

Comment: For Example we are using the Reporting Dlls Version 10.0.0.0 and 
the namespace for our reports is:
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition

Comment: I meant your ReportViewer DLL (Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common). I'm using VS2008 as well and the Version of the DLL is 10.0.0.0

Comment: You delete the reference and add it again. When you look for the dll, it should already be there in different versions. So you should take the largest version number as your report version is 2010/01 and mine is 2008/01.

Comment: There is only one Microsoft.winForm.ReportViewver 9.0.0.0 available even i installed reportviewver 10 from MS website still not getting it after a restart!

Comment: Sorry can't help you with this :-(

Comment: But You did for sure:-) Only problem is how to add ReportViewver 10.0.0.0 ... Need to find out how to..

Comment: Hey I did find a link for a download:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-Us/download/details.aspx?id=6442